# Trying to find the name of a specific location from tweets

Tags: machine-learning, twitter, nlp, tweetstream

I am trying to find the name of a specific location from tweets and performing sentiment analysis on the hits I get from the search. The problem I am facing is that, I am looking for a location whose name is suppose "Sammy's Tap and Grill", searching which I get no hits. I need to search something like "Sammys" or "Sammy's" to get some hits. Alternatively, when I search for "Empire State Building", I cannot search for "Empire" alone, it gives weird tweets including Mayan and Chola empires. So here I have to search with "Empire State Building" or "Empire State". So is there an NLP trick where I can do something and search for the best possible term from the full name of the location that gets most relevent hits? I was just able to make a solution where I was checking if the hits I get were nouns, because some places have names like "Excellent" and "Fantastic" and I didnt want adjectives to pop up. So is there some NLP way to solve my problem about searching a locationname  from a tweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is very similar to ***named entity recognition*** problem. You can try using standart named entity exctractors or train your own NER model.

There different libraries for NER, like

1. [Stanford NER](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html),
2. [SpaCy NER Tool](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-named-entities)
3. [NLTK NER module](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html)

In case if you want ***to train your own*** *Named Entity Recognition* ***model*** check this links:

1. [CRF git repository](https://github.com/aleju/ner-crf)
2. [Named Entity Recognition with Tensorflow](http://LSTM%20CRF%20named%20entity%20regocnition)

Good luck)

Comment: The tweets I am working with are higly unstructured. So I guess I'll have to train my own NER model. Thank you so much @rudolfe